# General-purpose sprite manager

Tags: software-development, images, animation

I'm looking to make a 2D game and I want something like [2D Toolkit](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v9pBYc9KmC8#t=181), specifically, the sprite management features. I want to have a GUI for managing bounding boxes, anchor points, sprite sheets, animation speeds, etc, and export to a non-proprietary format like xml.

It would be extremely tedious to do this all by hand. If a program like this exists, it would help me a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reccomend [Spriter](http://www.brashmonkey.com/index.htm).  It has (or will have once the full version comes out,) all the [features](http://www.brashmonkey.com/spriter_features.htm) that you require, and more!

It currently costs $25 for the full version license, with future updates, and this is expected to go up at the time of full release.